# Connect to oracle database, knowing only the database name

Tags: java, r, oracle

I have an existing connection in R, where I use DBI library to do the following:

```
con <- dbConnect(drv, username = "user", password = "pass", dbname = "mydatabase.world")
```

This creates the following connection:

```
User name:             user
Connect string:        mydatabase.world
Server version:        11.2.0.4.0 
Server type:           Oracle RDBMS 
Results processed:     0 
OCI prefetch:          FALSE 
Bulk read:             25 
Statement cache size:  0 
LOB prefetch size:     1024 
Open results:          0
```

I would like to do the same thing in Java. I browsed lots of tutorials, and arrived at this:

```
private static Connection getDBConnection() {

Connection dbConnection = null;

try {

    Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}

try {

    dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,
            DB_PASSWORD);
    return dbConnection;

} catch (SQLException e) {

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}

return dbConnection;

}
```

but I get this error:

```
The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

I could connect just with database name in R, how to do the same thing in Java?

My current DB_CONNECTION string is:

```
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydatabase.world";
```

tnsping:

```
Message 3511 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSMessage
 3512 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSAttempting to
contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = tcp.world)(PROTOC
OL = TCP)(Host = 10.3.0.70)(Port = 1532))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = LUCAS)))
Message 3509 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS'
```

---

**Solution**

For whatever reason, I could not use the database name in Java. Here is what I had to do:

1. Run tnsping (found in oracle directory, BIN subdirectory) with the database name as parameter

`tnsping mydatabase.world`

2. Then from there I got my `host name` and `SID`
3. The string is now:

`String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.3.0.70:1532:LUCAS";`

Comment: Please put the complete log of error rather than just one line. Thank you.

Comment: That's the complete log of error. There is nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> knowing only the database name

I don't really understand, according to your R code it seems to me that DB_USER = "user" and DB_PASSWORD = "pass".

Also did you try adding the port and the SID to your DB_CONNECTION String ?

```
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.3.0.70:1532:LUCAS";
```

I edited my post with your tnsping info.

Comment: what I mean is I dont know the port, I dont know the SID, I dont know the host, I only know the database name usr/pass and this is enough to connect in R

Comment: `String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydatabase.world:1521:MYSID"; ` does not work

Comment: You have to replace it with your real SID, MYSID is a name I made up to illustrate my example.

As Andrej pointed out you can use tnsping mydatabase.world.
the tnsping binary should be located in your $ORACLE_HOME folder

Comment: how do I know my SID? (I didn't have to provide it in R). tnsping is not a recognised command on my windows and ubuntu boxes

Comment: As Andrej pointed out you can use tnsping mydatabase.world. the tnsping binary should be located in your $ORACLE_HOME folder and create an alias for the next time

Comment: Andrej says that SID is mydatabase.world (he said provide SID as parameter and then gave that as parameter) @Andrej

Comment: I only have `client_32` and `client_64` folders on my machine inside `C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0`

Comment: From what I've read Andrej didn't told you that, he told you that you could get your SID by typing the comand : tnsping mydatabase.world
mydatabase.world is your db_host.
For example my db_host is 192.168.0 ....
and my SID is RTEIWE

Comment: I dont have any files called `tnsping` in `C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\`

Comment: Seems like you downloaded a lite version of Oracle without the developper tools. did you download Oracle Instant Client ? tnsping is not included, have a look at this discussion : https://community.oracle.com/thread/2156338

Comment: ok I got it, but still dont know how to build the string (added in EDIT)

Comment: it should be like this :private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydatabase.world:1532:LUCAS";

Comment: this doesn't work. It's fascinating that in R I can just provide dbname and connect, and in Java it seems impossible

Comment: I'm sorry for me this should have worked. I have no more ideas except checking your firewall settings .... I really hope that someone will help you to figure it out, or that you will come back to us with the answer.

Comment: is the format of the string correct? Some of the ones online included // signs

Comment: Now that you have the Oracle developper tools, fire up sqldevelopper (Oracle SQL Developper) and test your connection settings.

For me the format of the string is correct

Comment: I don't have dev tools, I found it in client_1 BIN folder :(

Comment: I changed the database name to host name from tnsping.. it worked

Comment: Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1):

If i understood corectly you are not sure about connection parameters as hosthame and port.
It seems that mydatabase.world is a dsn name. So parameters you needed can be located at dsn: `/etc/odbc.ini` or `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

Comment: where do I write this? I have no access to the db except for an R library to read data from it

Comment: Windows: 'tnsping' is not recognised as an internal or external command
Ubuntu: 'tnsping command not found'

Comment: It seems that mydatabase.world is a dsn name. So parameters you needed can be located at dsn:
`/etc/odbc.ini` or 
`/etc/odbcinst.ini`

Comment: R knows how to connects to the Oracle database as it reads connection parametrs from dsn file. `mydatabase.world` is a name of such connection but it says nothing about real database hostname, port, SID etc

Comment: How can I access those files though? I tried typing it into my browser, but it doesnt lead anywhere.